# Identify a ghost story about a mirror in a hotel room, possibly in Ireland

Tags: story-identification

As a child in Britain in the 1980s I remember reading a ghost story in a (1970s?) British compilation which went roughly like this:

- It is set in Ireland, or at least mentions an **Irish city**.
- The protagonist misses a **ferry**, and has to stay at a full **hotel**.
- There is one room, but the hotel keeper is reluctant to give it to him.
- The room contains a **mirror**.
- The protagonist falls asleep, but wakes during the night.
- He goes to the mirror. There is something wrong about his reflected image. It may be something to do with condensation or **drops of water** on the glass.
- ??? [I do not recall what happens; either I did not understand, or I skipped it because I was scared.]
- Much later, the protagonist is back in his own house. He passes a mirror, and notices that there are drops of water on it. [I did not understand the significance.]

The compilation may have been by Aidan Chambers; at any rate, it was 1960s-70s and of the same sort. I don't believe the story can be hopelessly obscure, but Google has not given the remotest clue. I just want to know what the story was actually about.

Comment: Maybe [Room 18](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?567897) by Aidan Chambers? Haven't been able to find much on it except for [a random quote](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Ln6CMP1KxM8J:www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flyblown+&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us): "The large looking glass above the fireplace was pockmarked with damp, as though huge flies had blown on it."

Comment: It sounds like that _must_ be it. I think it had a simple title. Thank you very much! I'll have to see if I can buy a copy and fill in the missing details!

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps [Room 18](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?567897) by Aidan Chambers (also credited under Malcolm Blacklin), first published in 1969. Has been in a few Aidan Chambers ghost stories anthologies.

Details are hard to come by, I have found only the the random quote in the comments of [merriam-webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flyblown)'s definition of "flyblown":

> reading short story "Room 18" by Aiden Chambers: "The large looking
> glass above the fireplace was pockmarked with damp, as though huge
> flies had blown on it."

And also a couple places that had a short blurb accompanying the story title (like [this one](http://vaultofevil.suddenlaunch3.com/index.cgi?board=ramsey&action=display&num=1164483469)):

> Room 18 - where a man sees Something in a mirror ....

Comment: Thank you again. I will accept this answer as soon as I find a copy to make absolutely sure.